# Android Indexoutofbounds Exception during Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, media-player, indexoutofboundsexception

I can't understand why I receive the IndexOutOfBound Exception during the reproduction of one of the 10 songs in my music game.
I think that even using asynctask.get() that waits until the computation finishes, somehow he skip the filling of the list with 10 songs info (dieciCanzoni).

Can you help me please?

Thank you!

Logcat:

```
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at com.guessthesetunes.Canzone.onCompletion(Canzone.java:539)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1528)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
11-26 10:29:49.441: E/AndroidRuntime(7509):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get the error on this line, that calls a method that initialize the mediaplayer:
            PlayStream(dieciCanzoni.get(i).get(0));

The code of the AsyncTask that I'm using:

```
class Json extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
List<String> canzoni = new ArrayList<String>(5);
ProgressDialog pDialog;
int[] arrayGenere;
Context context;

public Json(int[] arrayGenere,Context context) 
{
    this.arrayGenere = arrayGenere;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Preparazione Round...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    try
    {       
        int randomLookupId;
        JSONObject obj;                         
        JSONArray jsonArray;    

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            canzoni = new ArrayList<String>();

            obj = getJSONObject(scegliClassifica(arrayGenere));
            jsonArray = obj.getJSONArray("resultIds");

            randomLookupId = new Random().nextInt(jsonArray.length());  

            JSONObject finalObj = getJSONObject("http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id="+jsonArray.getString(randomLookupId)); 
            JSONArray finalJsonArray = finalObj.getJSONArray("results");    

            JSONObject returnObj = finalJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            canzoni.add(returnObj.getString("previewUrl"));
            canzoni.add(returnObj.getString("artistName"));
            canzoni.add(returnObj.getString("trackName"));
            canzoni.add(returnObj.getString("artistViewUrl"));
            canzoni.add(returnObj.getString("artworkUrl100"));

            Canzone.dieciCanzoni.add(i, new ArrayList<String>(canzoni));
        }
    }   
    catch (JSONException ignored)
    {
        ignored.getCause();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private String scegliClassifica(int[] arrayGenere)
{
    int randomArrayPosition = new Random().nextInt(arrayGenere.length);
    return "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/charts?cc=us&g="+arrayGenere[randomArrayPosition]+"&name=Songs&limit=300";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String stringa)
{
    pDialog.dismiss();
}

JSONObject getJSONObject(String url) throws IOException, MalformedURLException, JSONException
{

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DoneHandlerInputStream(in)));
        for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line = r.readLine())
        {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        return new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
    }
}
}
```

This is the call to the Asynctask:

```
try {
        new Json(arrayGenere,Canzone.this).execute().get(15000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT:

After changing the size of the JsonArray to JsonArray.lenght()-1, it doesn't work either!!!
For example, in one case the class Json has filled only 2 elements of the List, but I can't understand why!

Can you help me please guys?
Thanks

Comment: change `randomLookupId = new Random().nextInt(jsonArray.length());` to             randomLookupId = new Random().nextInt(jsonArray.length()-1);

Comment: Could you mark the line where you get the error in your code? That would make things easier. But most likely your arrayGenere is empty. Can you verify the size of it before trying to access items in it?

Comment: arrayGenere is always filled, because I pass the value of other initialized arrays of int[], based on the genre choosed by the user.

Comment: edited my question, but even changig the value returned to randomLookupId doesn't make it work! Help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remember the first element of an array is index 0. As such the length will be 1 higher than the highest index, so you need to subtract 1 from your `randomLookupId` before you use it.

(consider an array with length 1, you should always randomly select index 0)

Comment: Ok, like @thepoosh said in a comment. But now the logcat gives me another error: randomLookupId = new Random().nextInt(jsonArray.length()-1); ILLEGAL ARGUMENT EXCEPTION

Comment: Try
`randomLookupId = new Random().nextInt((jsonArray.length()-1));`

Answer (score 0):

In you `doInBackground` method How do you know that you are within the "legal size"?

Your whole method build on faulty/hardcoded assumptions...

Comment: can you explain better? Anyway I haven't posted the other classes, but I know the size because i choose a random value based on the length of the array!

Comment: JSONObject returnObj = finalJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
How do you make sure that there is 1 object in the finalJsonArray ?
Also why do you add the name final to your variable without making them final like 'final JSONObject finalJSONObject = new ....' ?

Comment: I'm sure that there is one object, because I retrieve a random song ID with the link above this one. so it will always be in position 0. For the 'final' thing, it's just a linguistical matter, I didn't know how to name it...loss of creativity ;)

Comment: Why don't you debug through it to find out which line it crashes on?

Comment: I tried, but it simply crashes on PlayStream method, that take the previewUrl and play it...but whrn the previewUrl is null, there it comes the exception!